# Cosmos DB - ExecuteNextAsync returns empty objects

Tags: c#, linq, azure, xamarin, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Xamarin app and I use Cosmos DB on Azure, on the DB side I have this kind of document :

[image]

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b84142d07bf8638bcf7a089"),
"business_id" : "5b81309a7dfa952bb4036f55",
"contentType" : "image",
"media" : "https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.30796.jpg",
"id" : "22155414-ee2b-3191-c180-3bc9d40db16b"
}
```

On the Xamarin side, I use the following code :

```
List<TempObject> TempObjects = new List<TempObject>(); 
Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId);
var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<TempObject>(collectionUri).AsDocumentQuery();
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    TempObjects.AddRange( await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TempObject>() );
}
```

Here is the data class definition :

```
class TempObject
{
    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
    //public string _id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "business_id")]
    public string business_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contentType")]
    public string contentType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "media")]
    public string media { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that it returns the right number of objects, but all the properties are null !

The collection has been created with the default settings and the database is almost empty, only 2 documents in this collection !

The code seems to follow exactly all the tutorials I have found !
Mainly this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/cosmosdb/consuming

Also, when I use the local CosmosDB emulator with the same database, it works, but not when it is on Azure ! Does it mean that my code is correct and that the issue is on the Azure side ?

Any idea of the issue ? Or a way to debug such kind of problem ?

Thanks

Edit : I have also try with the Cosmonaut API, here is the code:

```
var cosmosSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings("soclozecosmosdb", "https://soclozedb.documents.azure.com:443/", "E2ipML2QWNVjWITKhX0K0pn7ooCWxbkEk0xkQIC6QIWQCmMjsLU3D2SRTLaIk0dB3bm4k4mWhlpYYpbgsrk2xw==");

ICosmosStore<TempObject> store = new CosmosStore<TempObject>(cosmosSettings);
var users = store.Query().ToList();
```

But, the query returns 0 objects !

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but the `_id` property should look like this: `"_id": "ObjectId("5b84142d07bf8638bcf7a089")",` with proper double quotes around the ObjectId. Is that how it is? Other than that it looks like a mapping issue but your class looks correct.

Comment: I don't know about ObjectId ... this line is added automatically, I don't know what it is at all ! Thanks

Comment: Are you using the MongoDB api?

Comment: No, I'm in Xamarin and I use a NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core

Comment: I'm talking about the CosmosDB Mongo API.

Comment: Just tested with [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) (as I don't have all your data access code) and it looks like that both the CosmonautClient and the CosmosStore querying [return the correct results](https://i.imgur.com/iXqtMvG.png). Your problem is somewhere outside of the code you posted.

Comment: @NickChapsas I don't know what you mean with Cosmos DB Mongo API... I just use what is defined in the tutorial !

Comment: BTW, I use Cosmonaut too, but it returns 0 objects.

Comment: Just tested and it returns two object but it only maps the id propertyas you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/0k05LQS.png). That's because your documents look [like this](https://i.imgur.com/QnedFh0.png). Now, i don't know why they look like this but that's your problem. Also don't use `.ToList()` with Cosmonaut but `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Thanks @NickChapsas, I tried with ToListAsync but still have an empty result ! I use the Azure DataExplorer and my data looks like (See the edited question)  ! I don't know how you got this result ?

Comment: BTW, in your picture (https://i.imgur.com/QnedFh0.png) what is $v $t and the last "id" ? I have never inserted such data ?

Comment: You need to change `ICosmosStore<TempObject> store = new CosmosStore<TempObject>(cosmosSettings);` to `ICosmosStore<TempObject> store = new CosmosStore<TempObject>(cosmosSettings, "publication");` to point it to the collection.

Comment: Thanks, but it is exactly the same ! The users.count == 0 :-(

Comment: @NickChapsas please, can you tell me how you get this : (i.imgur.com/QnedFh0.png). I have used Studio 3T and the Azure Data Explorer, but I can't see that result ! When I use theses tools, I see the same result than in the screen shot in the question ! Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: I have some news, I have downloaded the local CosmosDB Emulator, I have add a few documents into the same DB/Collection. Locally, it works perfectly, but not on Azure !

Comment: Can you make sure that the Azure database is created with the SQL API selected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178963/discussion-between-krysalid-and-nick-chapsas).

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem can occur if, for whatever reason, you mistakenly subclass your data object as a Document. No reason to do that with the CosmosDB SDK.